# Is there a way to save resize cell automatically to text with openpyxl?

Tags: openpyxl

HI I am creating an xlsx file using openpyxl

and the I want to rearrange the cells per the text
is there a way to do this with python?

Thanks,

Comment: *I want to rearrange the cells per the text*
What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Columns have the [`bestFit`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl-worksheet-dimensions-module) attribute and cells can be set to wrap text using the [`Alignment`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html) attribute.

Comment: can you please give me an example of code
how to check give the colums this attribue?